# What happens if one's weekly fast/vrata falls on Dwadashi?

Tags: puranas, vrata, ekadashi

Lot of Hindus keep a fast on Tuesday and/or Saturdays. Now as per Puranas one should not keep a vrata on Dwadashi inadvertently or otherwise as it is a grave sin. For instance in Garuda Purana it is mentioned Gandhari kept a vrata on Dwadashi, and thus lost her 100 sons in battle.
Question is if the weekday fast falls on Dwadashi then what should one do ?

Comment: your reference is wrong it was told Gandhari fasted dasami sparsha ekadhasi.. means she fasted on dhasami

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Brihaspati (Nitisara) Samhita, Garuda Purana, some vratas can be kept on dwadashi:

[Chapter CXXXVI](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-garuda-purana-dutt/d/doc122616.html) - The Sravana Dvadasi Vratas etc

> The day of the twelfth phase of the moon’s increase in the month of Bhadra marked by the asterism shravana, is called Mahati Dvadashi. A fast observed under the auspices of this astral combination, bears immortal fruits.

Further, Agni Purana devotes three complete chapters dedicated to perform a fast on dwadashi

- [Chapter 188 - Vows observed on the twelfth lunar day](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-agni-purana/d/doc1083417.html)
- [Chapter 189 - Rules of observing Śrāvaṇadvādaśī-vrata](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-agni-purana/d/doc1083418.html)
- [Chapter 190 - Mode of practising Akhaṇḍadvādaśī-vrata](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-agni-purana/d/doc1083419.html)

---

`Now as per Puranas one should not keep a vrata on Dwadashi`

I think, That's in reference to, and for breaking the ekadashi fast (पारण), and not otherwise.

So, I guess there shouldn't be any problem if weekday fast coincide with a dwadashi, since dwadashi fasts doesn't seem to be blanket forbidden.

Answer (score 3):

Fasting is not prohibited on Dwadashis. Narada Purana lists the various Vratas that are performed on the Tithi.

Quoting from the book ["Essence of Narada Purana"](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/details/naradapurana13.html):

> As regards Dwadashis, details of ‘Vrata Pujas’ worshipping Vishnu
> Rupas viz. Keshava, Narayana, Madhava, etc.have been described from
> Marhasirsha to Kartika Months (Shukla Pakshas) along with the
> Puja-Vidhana. Following is gist of Vratas as follows): ‘Madana Vrata’
> is perfomed on Chaitra Shukla Dwadashi to dedicate it to Kaama Rupi
> Shri Hari. On this very day, ‘Bhartru Dwadashi’ is also observed by
> worshipping Lakshmi and Vishnu too. Similarly, Vratas aiming at
> various forms/ names of Vishnu are observed on the Dwadashis
> herebelow: Vaishakha Shukla/ Madhava, Jyeshtha Shukla/ Trivikaram,
> Shravana Shukla/ Shridhara, Bhadrapada Shukla/Vamana, and Aswin
> Shukla/ Padmanabha. The Kartika Krishna Vrata called ‘Govatsa Dwadashi
> Vrata’is addressed to Mother Cow reciting the Mantra: Ksheerodarnava
> Sambhootey Suraasura namaskrutey, Sarvadeva mayey Devi Sarva
> devailankrutey/ Maatarmaatargavaam Maatagruheenaarghyam namostutey/
> (Mother! Gomata! You manifested from the Ocean of Milk, ornamented by
> all Devas, worshipped by Devas and Danavas alike; kindly accept this
> ‘Arghya’ followed by Puja and ‘Nivedana’.On this day of Govatsa
> Dwadashi, devotees should avoid oil-fried items, Cow-milk, curd, ghee
> etc. On Margasirsha Shukla Dwadashi, ‘Sadhya Vrata’ is performed by
> assuming the Twelve Sadhya Ganaas, Viz. Manobhava, Praana, Nara,
> Apaana, Veeryavan, Chiti, Haya, Naya, Hamsa, Narayana, Vibhu and
> Prabhu. The Ganaas are invoked into a rice spreading and worshipped,
> after which request Lord Narayana to be pleased. On this very day, a
> ‘Dwadasha  -aditya’ Vrata be also performed by doing Puja to Dhata,
> Mitra, Aryama, Pusha, Shakra, Amsha, Varuna, Bhaga, Twashta,
> Viviswaan, Savita and Vishnu.

Not aware of the story about Gandhari you mentioned but looks like she was fasting on the previous day (Ekadashi Vrata) and did another Vrata on the next day (Dwadashi). Now this is not possible or allowed because not breaking the Ekadashi fast is an offence.